# Dynamically Set Bootstrap class variable in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically set the bootstrap `"class="` variable in Django to a value from the model.

The template looks like this (when "statically" set):

```
<strong><span class="label label-success"> It Worked! </span></strong>
```

I would like to dynamically set the `"class ="` and I have tried follow the following but seem to have issues passing `{{challenge.labelbx}}` into the span tag :

```
<strong><span class={{challenge.labelbx}}> It Worked! </span></strong>
```

From the Challenge Model:

```
def labelbx(self): #These are bootstrap label colors
    if self.consistency_percentage() > 79:
        return "label label-success" # green
    elif self.consistency_percentage() > 69:
        return "label label-info" #blue
    elif self.consistency_percentage() > 59:
        return 'label label-warning' #orange
    elif self.consistency_percentage() > 49:
        return "label"
    else:
        return "label"
```

From the View:

```
def public_scorecard_page(request):

    c = Challenge.objects.get(user__exact = request.user,chal_status=1)

    return render(request, 'public_scorecard.html', {'challenge': c})
```

Comment: please post your challenge model and the corresponding view function.

Comment: Jay, I posted the model and view code. I appreciate any feedback you can offer.

Comment: Seems like you miss a ": Do <span class="{{ challenge.labelbx }}"> OR change your labelbx function to return strings like this: return '"label label-success"' <-- Note the " and '.